# Kак найти и сгруппировать в новый столбец одинаковые слова?

Tags: python, csv

Есть CSV, в котором есть колонка с названием `Name`, в ней указаны слова, которые повторяются больше двух раз, мне надо эти слова, в моем случае это `Бухгалтерский аудит` перенести в колонку с названием `duplicate`. Таких слов может быть много, большой CSV и чтобы дубликаты перечислялись через запятую

```
определение суд экспертизы
аудиторская компания +в Москве
аудиторская проверка -ооо -сколько -стоить
Бухгалтерский аудит предприятия
Бухгалтерский аудит бизнеса
```

Вот, надо чтобы получилось примерно так

```
duplicate
бухгалтерский аудит, что нибудь еще и тд
```

Не нужно учитывать склонения, времена и прочее, нужно только точное соответствие, и к регистру не чувствителен.

Comment: Что вы понимаете в этом контексте под - "одинаковые слова". Не могли бы вы дать более понятный пример из вашего CSV и желаемого результата?

Comment: у меня csv слишком большой. В общем, в csv есть колонка Name, в ней названия, пример:
определение суд экспертизы
аудиторская компания +в Москве
аудиторская проверка -ооо -сколько -стоить
Бухгалтерский аудит предприятия
Бухгалтерский аудит бизнеса

Если в столбце больше двух одинаковых слов, в моем случае это бухгалтерский аудит, то мне надо перенести их в column 'duplicate'

Comment: У вас под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1014756/edit), там и дайте пример ваших данных и желаемого результата. Пока вы этого не сделаете, то врядли получите  вразумителльный ответ. Советую [ознакомится тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7061).

Comment: О, морфологический разбор слов — та ещё тема. Смотрите словари правописания и как они работают. Нахождение дубликатов по сравнению с предыдущим моментом — детский лепет.